# Ruby Openssl not being found in NET::HTTP

Tags: openssl, net-http, ruby-1.8.7

I'm getting the following error:

> /Users/user_name/.rbenv/versions/1.8.7-p375/lib/ruby/1.8/net/https.rb:124:in
>   `use_ssl=': uninitialized constant Net::HTTP::OpenSSL (NameError)

So, I opened up the https file and changed one thing just to see what would happen, I did this:

```
@ssl_context = ::OpenSSL::SSL::SSLContext.new
```

If you can't see it, I added `::` to `OpenSSL::SSL::SSLContext.new` in the method:

```
def use_ssl=(flag)
```

and the problem went away.

Now obviously I can't edit the source code directly for ruby libs so I added the following to the top of my script to act as a patch:

```
module Net
  class HTTP

    def use_ssl=(flag)
      flag = (flag ? true : false)
      raise IOError, "use_ssl value changed, but session already started"\
          if started? and @use_ssl != flag
      if flag and not @ssl_context
        @ssl_context = ::OpenSSL::SSL::SSLContext.new
      end
      @use_ssl = flag
    end
  end
end
```

However I'm getting an error:

> scripts/get_social_data.rb:27:in `use_ssl=': uninitialized constant OpenSSL (NameError)

Despite having done:

```
require 'openssl'
```

at the top of my script.

Why is `OpenSSL` not existing even though I'm requiring it?

I'm guessing I'm missing somthing but I honestly can't see it.

EDIT:

Well, I noticed that Openssl (I'm maintaining this project) was in the gemfile, I'm pretty sure it's not supposed to be there, I uninstalled it but It's still not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so, after looking around the internet and trying various things I found a fix for my issue, I had to re-install ruby 1.8.7-p375 using the following command:

> RUBY_CONFIGURE_OPTS=--with-openssl-dir= rbenv install 1.8.7-p375

The opensslDir can be found, at least on osx and installed with homebrew like this:

> brew list openssl

You'll get a bunch of dir's, just copy the bit that's in all of them, it might look like somthing like this:

> /usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2h